# How to install tkinter for python3.10.6 on CentOS7?

Tags: python, tkinter, centos7

First, I installed openssl 1.1.1q package using the following source on CentOS7.
(https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz)

Second, I installed tcl/tk packages using the following sources.
(https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8.6.12-src.tar.gz
https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tk8.6.12-src.tar.gz)

Finally, I installed python 3.10.6 using the following source.
(https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.6/Python-3.10.6.tar.xz)

However, I can't use tkinter module.
For example, when I import tkinter I get the bellow message.

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug 18 2022, 11:15:38) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

The yum doesn't support the python 3.10.x version. How can I resolve this problem without yum?
What should I do to use tkinter?

Comment: Did you build Python using the source? If yes, then you need to have `tk` and `tcl` development packages installed in order to build the `tkinter` module.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, I do. And I installed tk and tcl using the source too. (https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html) However, I still can't build tkinter module.

Comment: It means that the building environment cannot find the tk and tcl include files and libraries.  Why don't you install the development packages provided by CentOS? I have no problem building Python 3.10.6 in my RHEL 6 (older than CentOS 7) with tkinter module.

Comment: @acw1668 I've just tried what you said. I installed tkinter using `sudo yum install python3-tkinter`. It doesn't works for python 3.10.6 but works only for python 3.6.8. What the developement package you installed? `[dongwook@DW-CentOS7-VM Python-3.10.6]$ python3.6 -m tkinter
[dongwook@DW-CentOS7-VM Python-3.10.6]$ python3.10 -m tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_detai...blabla...`

Comment: I also installed tk-devel and tcl-devel using yum too. It still doesn't work for python 3.10.6...

Comment: You need to look into the config.log and build log to see why the tkinter module failed to build.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing tkinter in a wrong way, it is like this

```
import tkinter
```

tkinter is a preinstalled library in python, to test it open cmd and type

```
python -m tkinter
```

a small window should appear, if it does then it is working

Comment: `tkinter` cannot be installed by `pip`.

Comment: sorry didn't realise

Comment: Unfortunately, 'python -m tkinter' also doesn't work... I think there are some problems using tcl/tk developement packages installed by the source.